# Regex ignore succeeding word occurence

Tags: regex

If i have these strings:

```
banana not included. apple included.
banana, apple included.
```

the regex below returns a match on both strings but I don't want a match on the first string

```
banana.*(?<!(\bnot ))inc(\.|luded)?
```

What am I missing in my regex to achieve my desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few different regexp engines. What language/engine are you using?

Comment: C#, .NET.

Appreciate your help Emily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from only two examples, but perhaps this is what you want?

```
banana(?!.*\bnot\b).*\binc(\.|luded)?
```

Comment: Thanks Laurence!

I think we are close but I found another variation where the string is "orange included. banana included. apple not included.". This does not give me a match.

Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better solution than Laurence, but to answer the why portion of your question, I believe that the `.*` has already consumed the `not` that your lookbehind is looking for.